# path.join in require statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, dynamic

I try to use `Path.join` in `require` statement like this:

```
import Path from 'path'

const assetPath = Path.join(process.cwd(), `./lib/asset-manifest.json`)

console.log(assetPath)
'/home/dev/Website/lib/asset-manifest.json'

console.log(
  assetPath === '/home/dev/Website/lib/asset-manifest.json'
)
true

const assets = require(assetPath)
```

But that throws error that:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/dev/Website/lib/asset-manifest.json'
```

Though the file is there and `require` works if I put the string manually in it:

```
const assets = require('/home/dev/Website/lib/asset-manifest.json')
```

So I wonder why does not `Path.join` works in `require` ?

Best regards

Comment: A *string* is a *string* and *two* identical strings are still identical. Have you tried to assert that they are the same? `console.log(assetPath === '/home/dev/Website/lib/asset-manifest.json');` because the use of a variable or literal should have no effect on `require()`.

Comment: @cgTag yes they are equal.

Comment: do you really have any file on this path, try in system terminal type: cat /home/dev/Website/lib/asset-manifest.json     can you see any text?

Comment: @VadimHulevich Yes `cat` works. I use webpack. Might maybe be a webpack issue?

Comment: Why are you using webpack with nodejs? Are you building a library?

Comment: Yes kind of! And pdf

Comment: well, try see what's goin on in bundle file, maybe inside of this bundle file you have some errors

Comment: I think you need to use `require.context`. I'd post an answer, but I've never used it before. Maybe someone else can help. https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/context#requirecontext

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't be using require here if you're using webpack. If you are loading files from outside the scope of the project, then maybe you should use `fs` instead.

Comment: @cgTag I will try it and write response. But great suggestion:)

Comment: @cgTag __non_webpack_require__ seems to work with dynamic path in require

Comment: Yeah, when you use webpack only use require for things you want included in the bundles. If it's a local resource the user provides, then you should use `fs`. I've never used webpack with nodejs for that reason. npm does a good job of packaging things anyway.

Comment: Why are you using an absolute path if it's relative to the project?  Couldn't you do something like `require('./lib/asset-manifest.json')`.  If not, why are you using `process.cwd()`, that's going to change based on where you're executing the command, you should use something like `os.homedir()` instead.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want it in the home directory, you could use `__dirname`

Comment: I didnot used `process.cwd()`,and my code is not typescript, This is my code  http://prntscr.com/10uvrcw

Comment: @Reactgular , how we can use `require.context` ?, that is webpack configuration ? , or, can we replace `require` with `require.context` via webpack configuration ?

Answer (score 2):

```
import path from 'path';

// you can use process.cwd() if you want
const assetPath = path.join(path.dirname(require.main.filename), `lib/asset-manifest`);

const test = () => {
  var assets = require(assetPath);
  console.log(assets);
};

export default test();
```

You need to surround the require inside a function. Otherwise require will run before the path is assigned to the assetPath variable. This is because require is SYNC and runs in perspective to file or function in which it is called. Because you are stating this is required it gets immediately executed before anything else.

Best practice moving forward is to stop using require for json files. Require caches content and so if the JSON file changes in production your users may get old data. Instead use `fs.readfile(path, (err, data) => JSON.parse(data))`

There is a webpack configuration you may want to try in your case.

[WEBPACK DOCS: Don't Check Require Dependencies](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-variables/#__webpack_require__-webpack-specific)

[WEBPACK DOCS: Generate Require Func](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-variables/#__non_webpack_require__-webpack-specific)

```
const requireJSON = typeof __webpack_require__ === "function" ? __non_webpack_require__ : require;
const assets = requireJSON(assetPath);
```

This should return all possible paths for the require.

Comment: is there webpack configuration to automatically solve this problem ?

Comment: I have a questions. Are you trying to defer this require/ import to runtime or do you want this compiled?

Comment: See updated answer! Does this help or work for you?

Comment: @MERN I wanted to follow back up and see if you were able to review my response. Please let me know if you have any other questions or if I can help any further. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

webpack is a static module bundler, `require` here is not like the `require` in `nodejs`.

The previous one includes files at static compilation phase, the another includes files at runtime.

Your case, `const assets = require(assetPath)`, `assetPath` is not defined at static compilation phase, that's why throw the error.

Let's see the bundled result:

```js
// const assets = require(assetPath);
const assets = await __webpack_require__("./ lazy recursive")(assetPath);

// below is the "./ lazy recursive" module
function webpackEmptyAsyncContext(req) {
    // Here Promise.resolve().then() is used instead of new Promise() to prevent
    // uncaught exception popping up in devtools
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        var e = new Error("Cannot find module '" + req + "'");
        e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND';
        throw e;
    });
}
webpackEmptyAsyncContext.keys = () => ([]);
webpackEmptyAsyncContext.resolve = webpackEmptyAsyncContext;
webpackEmptyAsyncContext.id = "./ lazy recursive";
module.exports = webpackEmptyAsyncContext
```

Comment: what means `webpack is a static module bundler,` ?

Comment: is there other method instead of webpack ?

Comment: @MERN You can use 'gulp' instead. BTW, the module system used in nodejs is commonjs, you should use `require/exports` to include your files instead of `import/export`